# How to create custom regex pattern in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have text box that can accept only numbers (floated number too (1.5 or 2.5 like this) with percentage symbol at end of the number but this % symbol not mandatory it an optional. I want do this using regular expression in javascript.

Comment: Ex: 10 or 10.5 or 10% or 10.5%

Comment: Please share with us what you've tried so far so we can help you.

Comment: <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<input type="text" id="mynumber"/>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById('mynumber').value;
    var patt1 = /\d+\.?/g;
    var result = str.match(patt1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this expression `/^\d+(\.\d+)?%?$/`

Comment: @ Evan Griffin - Thanks lot its working great.